# Can't congress override Trump's assumed veto of the temporary spending bill?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, congress, government-shutdown, veto

The senate unanimously passed a spending bill a few days ago to keep the government funded until mid-February. Trump stated that he will veto it because it doesn't include funding for a wall. There is likely support in the house to also pass a wall-less spending bill with a large majority.

Since both chambers seem to have a supermajority that support, they can override any veto that Trump will give. Why don't they just push this bill through, veto or not?

I know that when congress is not in session, the president can "pocket veto" the bill, but many news organizations are expecting the shutdown to continue after congress reconvenes in January.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because you're asking us to speculate on interior motivations.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I am curious if there are any exterior motivations (or procedural reasons they can't just override)

Comment: @DanielM. I think you might want to word this question as "Is there any reason Congress can't override the veto?" As it stands it sounds like the question is about motives for not doing it.

Comment: i think this is a good question. I am also wondering if spending bills have to be agreed by the president.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a shutdown end if an agreement is never reached?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37635/how-does-a-shutdown-end-if-an-agreement-is-never-reached)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They can, with 2/3 majority in both houses (US Constitution, Article 1, Section 7, clause 2)...but they have to agree to actually hold that vote.

Currently, the Senate has indicated that it will not do so, without the bill being something the President will not veto. So effectively, they are choosing not to create a scenario where they would have the option to override the veto.

Comment: Republicans don't want to expose themselves as being for or against the funding of the wall. As usual they are trying to play both sides

Comment: To be precise, refusing to vote on a bill that the president is expected to veto isn't the same thing as refusing to override the veto.  A veto override requires two votes: one to pass the bill, and one to override the veto, which can only occur after the president actually vetoes the bill.